# SQL passing date as parameter?

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm pretty new to coding and SQL. I have the following (part of) code, which works, but dates should passed as parameter instead. How do i do that?

```
sqlStr = "DECLARE @MYDATE DATETIME, @MYDATE2 DATETIME"
sqlStr &= " SET @MYDATE = '" & fromDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") & "'" & ""
sqlStr &= " SET @MYDATE2 = '" & toDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") & "'" & ""

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, conn)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "DevLog")
da.Dispose()
Return ds
```

I need to do that `.ToString` operation, because dates coming from system are `xx.xx.xxxx (fi-FI)` and not `xx-xx-xxxx (en-US)` as SQL want's them (damn americans... :)).

So, I want to pass those dates as SQL parameter, like `@fromDate = fromDate`, but as I am new to coding and SQL in general, I need help. Where and how do I insert??

```
command.parameters.Add(@fromDate, DATETIME)

command.parameters.Add(@toDate, DATETIME)
```

EDIT: Sorry, I made a mistake. Actually what I ment to say was:

```
command.parameters.Add("@toDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = toDate
```

I should somehow pass fromDate and toDate as correct DATETIME parameters form in SQL string (@fromdate and @toDate) and not the way I'm doing it now... as ToString conversion.

@Saagar Elias Jacky

```
sqlStr = "DECLARE @MYDATE DATETIME, @MYDATE2 DATETIME"
sqlStr &= " SET @MYDATE = '" & fromDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") & "'" & ""
sqlStr &= " SET @MYDATE2 = '" & toDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") & "'" & ""
sqlStr &= " SELECT FixedDate, persons.FirstName, persons.lastName, TimeStampRecord, HoursSpent, HoursSpentRow, HoursSpentType"
sqlStr &= " FROM DevLog"
sqlStr &= " INNER JOIN Persons ON DevLog.OwnerUserID=Persons.UserID"
sqlStr &= " WHERE TimeStampRecord=1"
sqlStr &= " AND FixedDate BETWEEN @MYDATE AND @MYDATE2"
```

Comment: Why are you using a DECLARE statement and where are these variables used in DB?

Comment: Dates do not have a format, American or otherwise.  They are however displayed to humans in various formats.  The big problem would be that SQL are you adding or inserting?

Comment: Here is the whole SQL string:

Comment: Get rid of everything before "SELECT" in the SQL string.  Dates are a values.  A finnish date means the same thing as a french one; they are just *displayed* differently to French *people* or Finnish *people*.  Your DB is not a person, so a proper DateTime var will work fine.

Comment: If you mean: " AND FixedDate BETWEEN " &fromdate &" AND " &toDate &" , it wont work, beacause actual query string look like: "AND FixedDate BETWEEN 10.3.2015 AND 25.3.2015" and that does not work because SQL wants the date to be 03-10-2015 for example.

Comment: The answer has it right. As a practice, be sure to not directly add variables to a SQL string you build like this in your code - otherwise, SQL injection is a big risk in your code as posted.

Comment: Dates are simply VALUES (specifically the number of ticks since 1/1/0001) they do not have a format.  The `DateTime` Type knows *you* are Finnish and so it displays to you as `dd.MM.yyyy`. Your DB is not Finnish - it is CultureInvariant so it will read it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM DevLog "
sqlStr &= " INNER JOIN Persons ON DevLog.OwnerUserID=Persons.UserID"
sqlStr &= " WHERE TimeStampRecord = 1"
sqlStr &= " AND FixedDate BETWEEN @MYDATE AND @MYDATE2"

Dim ds As DataSet       

Using sqlComm As New SqlCommand(sqlStmt, sqlConn)
    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromDate", fromDate)
    sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@toDate", toDate)

    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlStmt, sqlConn)
    ds = New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "DevLog")
    da.Dispose()

End Using
```

Not tested, but hope it helps

Comment: Would like to know if one of the comments or my answer was helpful. Not telling the community if a challenge is solved is not so nice ...

Comment: I'm not going to do work on easter holiday. I will get back with an answer as soon as have time to work on the code.

Comment: wish you a nice weekend

Comment: Thomas, I did do a little work now in the evening after all. I had a little epiphany and your code is essentially correct. So in other word, I was able to correct my code with the help of yours. Thank you very much. Could not vote it up because I don't have the "reputation".